# RGB colors look different in Android emulator vs every other Mac app

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

Colors look very different in Android emulator or Android device when drawing using `Canvas` and `Paint` compared with Adobe Photoshop or Google Chrome running in the same Mac (and same screen).

See the next screenshot to see the difference. On the left side is a [website](https://color.adobe.com/Ignite-color-theme-9024899/edit/?copy=true&base=2&rule=Custom&selected=4&name=Copy%20of%20Ignite&mode=rgb&rgbvalues=0.996078431372549,0.8666666666666667,0.07058823529411765,0.9333333333333333,0.4588235294117647,0.13725490196078433,0.9058823529411765,0.17647058823529413,0.5725490196078431,0.13725490196078433,0.6980392156862745,0.6588235294117647,0.12941176470588237,0.20392156862745098,0.40784313725490196&swatchOrder=0,1,2,3,4) in Google Chrome and on the right side is the Android emulator with two squares which should match the two colors in the website.

[image: Website vs Android emulator comparison]

If I copy and paste the RGB colors to Adobe Photoshop, the colors match with the ones displayed in the website. If I run my Android app in a real device, the colors still look like the colors displayed in the Android emulator.

The code I used to draw the `Canvas` is this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
        imageView.getWidth(),
        imageView.getHeight(),
        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

Paint paint1 = new Paint();
paint1.setColor(Color.parseColor("#23B2A8"));
canvas.drawRect(0, 0, 200, 200, paint1);

Paint paint2 = new Paint();
paint2.setColor(Color.parseColor("#213468"));
canvas.drawRect(200, 0, 400, 200, paint2);

imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

There is a big difference. Am I doing something wrong? I want the colors to look similar.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Try adding `FF` to each color (`#FF23B2A8`, `#FF213468`), to indicate fully-opaque on the alpha channel.

Comment: That, or use `Bitmap.Config.RGB_565` if you don't need to set alpha. You can even use `Color.rgb()` or `Color.argb()` instead of hexadecimal.

Comment: @CommonsWare converting to `"#FF23B2A8"` and `"#FF213468"` did not have an effect.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider using `Bitmap.Config.RGB_565` instead of `Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888` did not improve the colors. I will try the other option.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider changing to `paint1.setColor(Color.rgb(35, 178, 168))` and `paint2.setColor(Color.rgb(33, 52, 104))` did not work.

Comment: I found what is the problem, thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you share your solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in the `ImageView` definition. I had an `android:tint` attribute.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/myImageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:tint="#55ff0000" />
```

Removing the attribute solves the issue.